# Добавление нескольких товаров в корзину

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть комплект товаров и нужно добавить все товары в комплекте в корзину. Сейчас добавляю товар вот так:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" class="btn-buy" onclick="addCart(this);">Купить</a>
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$produсt->id?>" name="id"/>
```

При нажатии на `"Купить"` обрабатывается функция `addcart`, куда передается один `id` товара.

```
function addCart(btn) {
    $this = $(btn);

    var id = $this.siblings('input[name=id]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/cart/add_cart',
        dataType : "json",
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            'id':id
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            $(".total_count").text(data.total_count + " шт.");
            $(".sum").text(data.total_price);
            $('.name_modal').html(data.addProduct.title);
            $('.price_modal').html(data.addProduct.price);
            $('.img_modal').attr('src', '/' + data.addProduct.img);
            $('#myModal').reveal({});
        }
    });
}
```

А вот как добавить несколько товаров при нажатии на `"Купить"`? [Пример](http://rusjeweller.kz/catalog/product/148), чтобы вы понимали что такое комплект. Ниже товара показан комплект. Хочу добавить кнопку `"Купить"`, и чтобы все товары в комплекте добавлялись в корзину.

Comment: Почему бы вам не сделать дополнительную кнопку для покупки комплекта? И через неё передавать айдишники всех в комплетке. Передавать json-ом массив в модель и так формировать корзину.

Answer (score 1):

Я как правило в таких случаях использую форму+serialize+eventpreventdefalt+ajax(а вернее его младшего брата)

```js
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $.post('/cart/add_cart',{
                      'act':'add_to_bascket'
                       ,'data':$(this).serializeArray()
                     },function(data){
                         $(".total_count").text(data.total_count + " шт.");
                         $(".sum").text(data.total_price);
                         $('.name_modal').html(data.addProduct.title);
                         $('.price_modal').html(data.addProduct.price);
                         $('.img_modal').attr('src', '/' + data.addProduct.img);
                         $('#myModal').reveal({});
                     });
});
```

ajax - лучше конечно, поскольку в случае неудачи он может отправить повторно или сообщить пользователю об альтернативном варианте чтобы $.post(); работал необходимо подключить библиотеку jquery.

Мои ответы как правило минусуют и не объясняют почему - возможно это будет последний мой ответ, буду рад если помог.

Comment: необязательно использовать событие $('form').submit( можно и другое, главное здесь $('form').serializeArray(), а уже в форме может быть неограниченное количество товара